# How to fix woocommerce cart page problem?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Have an issue with my cart. when in cart and you update the quantity it buffers around the thumbnail image for the product., however when it is doing that if you f5 to refresh it becomes ok.
url:  http://iviewdata.com

I think it's happened website speed but website is good

Comment: The class of the image change completely, from img class to just a "data-echo". Do you have custom code? plugin? Changing to a simple "src" fix it, but it's weird that change it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the cart gets refreshed every time you update the quantity and returns the cart html with the latest data. Since you are lazy loading the images with data-eco attribute, when the cart HTMl is returned the first image is returned with data-echo attribute and not src attribute.

The solution to this is to add a condition to show images ie one which appears by default and one which appears on hover only on product archive / list page. If it is cart page simply do not show the image on hover. This will solve the issue.

You can use `is_shop() || is_product_category()` to get this sorted.